# How can I keep track of subscribers if they unsubscribe

Tags: twilio

When someone wants to receive sms message updates, they can subscribe on my website.

If they reply STOP on any of my messages, twilio will then stop sending them messages.

Is there a webhook where twilio can send me a notification that someone has unsubscribed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no webhook to say that a user has unsubscribed. However you will get the regular webhook with the message they sent.

So, you can look for messages that only contain ["STOP", "STOPALL", "UNSUBSCRIBE", "CANCEL", "END", and "QUIT"](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-) and update your database, or whatever you need, at that point.

Comment: But if they send "STOP please" it will not unsubscribe correct?   Also, If they send 'stop' and then I try and send an sms to their phone number, what will happen?

Comment: Correct, the message has to be "STOP" (or one of the other alternatives) only. If you try to reply to a "STOP" message or send another message later your message won't be sent and you will get an error returned from the API.

Comment: If someone sends a "STOP", what happens if I try and send a message to that user again? is it blocked?

Comment: Yes, if someone sends "STOP" you won't be able to message them until they send "START", "YES" or "UNSTOP" to unblock you.

Comment: So if they subscribe 2 months in the future on the website, the SMS won't be sent to them b/c then send "STOP" 2 months ago?   They will never know to send "START" at that point?

Comment: If you're worried about this, I'd keep a record of the numbers that send any of the STOP words to you and if they then subscribe again to your service later you can check against that list and be able to tell them that they'll need to text "START" in order to receive the messages.